# How do i make my logo fit in my nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I have a big transparent logo and i placed it in place of the old logo that came with the theme i downloaded but it doesn't scale according to the navigation bar

I can reduce the size of the logo in photoshop but i feel like that's not the best way to fix this issue

Here's the code i have for the logo

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a></div>
```

How do i fix the logo so it fits inside of my nav bar..

Here's my entire nav bar html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- Logo -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Navmenu -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#home">Home.</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Menus.</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="./breakfast.html">All Day Breakfast</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./lunch.html">Lunch</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./childrenmenu.html">Children's Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./coffeeandcake.html">Coffee and Cakes</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#about">Location.</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#cater">Catering.</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#about">About.</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#contact">Contact.</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Some more code would be nice. Especially a fiddle or so.

Comment: For as far as I know, the Bootstrap navbar has a fixed height, so what's the problem with resizing the image? Alternatively, you could add `height` and `width` using either CSS or HTML, like they do [in the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image).

Comment: I added my entire nav bar. Wouldn't it pixelate on higher resolutions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general, whenever you're playing around with the fitting of an image, these are the four CSS attributes you're looking for.

```
.img-responsive {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 72px;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

In my snippet, we're telling the image to automatically size itself. `<img>` tags will try to retain aspect ratio unless explicitly instructed otherwise. The two `max-` attributes dictate the largest dimensions we want. If we upload an image that's 300px wide and 72px tall, for instance, it will end up smaller than our maximum height and at 250px wide.

To vertically center the image, you'll want to do this:

```
line-height: 72px; /* whatever the fixed height of the bar is */
vertical-align: middle;
```

If your image is the exact height of the navbar, try using `vertical-align: top` if that looks off.

Comment: But if i add max-height and width it will pixelate on higher resolutions right

Comment: No. If you're asking about image DPI on mobile views, the convention is typically to make a logo that is 2x what the space needs and shrink it by half. You may also use the srcset attribute: https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/

Comment: But image resolution on mobile views is not the same as pixel resolution. On a 2x mobile phone, every resolution pixel is actually 4 draw pixels. 2px is still 2px, but on an image it's 4px of image.

Comment: I did that but my logo is not properly centered vertically, Can you please check my code in the first post and tell me how i can center it vertically?

Comment: Edited my post. Since Images are considered `inline-block` elements by default, the trick is to resize the line to be the same height as the bar and to instruct it to position correctly that way.